# How can ı get cookie value in js mvc asp core 3.0 project?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, cookies

How can ı Access my cookie value ?

I need to get cookie value UserID ı read cookie UserID  but ı don't Access cookie in js and with model.

I am new mvc, I am using core identity.

I am tried to request.cookie in js , but its not correct way to get cookie

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.Net Core, create cookies by js in following is not working (.Net Core can not get cookies).

```js
<script>
    document.cookie = "username=John Doe";
</script>
```

It need to use `encodeURIComponent` to encoding.

```js
<script>
    var cookieValue = encodeURIComponent("John Doe");
    document.cookie = "username=" + cookieValue;
</script>
```

and C# code :

```cs
public IActionResult ReadCookies()
{
    //read cookie from Request object  
    string cookieValueFromReq = Request.Cookies["username"];
    ViewBag.Message = cookieValueFromReq;
    return View();
}
```

and it will get the cookies create by javascript.